# Today’s Extension Using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, today-extension

I'm trying to make a widget game, is it possible to use SpriteKit within a Today Extension?. I've been searching for similar posts but I've only found a question related to using SpriteKit in a AppleWatch extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also working on some game in the today screen. So far I have found 3 solutions which working solid:

1. Like mentioned working with UIKIT
2. Use SpriteKit in a **minimal** way
3. Using offscreen images for rendering

The problem on solution 2 is, that it's very unreliable. Even calling regularly `completionHandler!(NCUpdateResult.newData)` has not worked.
So it's just the limited usage of **SKAction** at the end which has bring a lot.

Solution 3 is also good and works quite solid. Of course you must reinvent the wheel and can not use the nice features of SpriteKit. But because I've used this approach already in watchOS games, it was not much effort to use in Extensions.

I recommend solution 3 because you have full control and it works solid.

Comment: what's "minimal" in this case?

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible. I think you are aiming to build something like the popular "Steve" Widget Game, and I believe that is a SpriteKit Game built into a Today Extension.

To begin, I would suggest to fully understand Today Extensions and it's limits and then fully understanding SpriteKit and the limits that it has.

Something you really want to focus on is making an extremely efficient piece of app. All around, from the actual code and how your code runs. This is due to the fact that Today Extensions are not really apps but "extensions" to your device so if you have a game that is graphics intensive or memory intensive, your app will crash.

Comment: Yes thank you for your reply! i been messing around with the extensions and I am aiming for a simple game. I have tried so far running my app in the  TodayViewController, but some how when Im trying to present an Scene from the TodayViewController,  its not happening but no error in the simple code. Do you know why?

Comment: Two reasons.... 1) the device/simulator may be running on a higher target iOS release. Make sure that the target iOS is lower or the same as the device/simulator in the build settings. I usually test with a "hello world" app to just see if everything is displaying properly(to make sure all of the set up semantic setup stuff was completed properly). 2) the app may be consuming too much memory(remember today extensions have different limits from actual dedicated apps)... Observe memory limits and check if that's the case.

Comment: Can you please provide me a simple sample project or piece of code presenting an Sprite-kit Scene in a Today's Widget, It can be showing an image or anything I just want to make sure because it seems that when I try to run images in the TodayViewController everything works fine and when I run the Default Sprite-kit code as an normal app it works fine as well. It would be greatly appreciated thank you!! Once again for your time

Comment: Hey guys, I guess this answer comes a little bit late but it's something. I'm the developer of "Steve - The Jumping Dinosaur Widget Game" and I also had trouble trying to use SpriteKit inside the Today Extension. As the reply below states, I opted for UIKit it's also really powerful for simple games but as R S said, the notification center is really limited and you have to play with it a little to know them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's always nice to here from the developer of the original game. To OP, UIKit would be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried develop game in spriteKit for ios today extension, added SKViews to UIView, but it did not work. It seems like scene not loading in today extensions. I think it is not possible - use spriteKit in today extension.  But i found good solution - using UIKit instead spriteKit. It is very powerfull framework for game developing, and i think Steve game developing via UIKit. You can check adding dynamics via UIKit in this sample: https://www.raywenderlich.com/50197/uikit-dynamics-tutorial

Also i can upload sample of using UIKit in today extension game developing on github if needed.

Comment: Hi Ivan, i found a way how to use Spritekit into a Today Extension. It is possible but it uses a very few memory.I tried the Default Spritekit sample with the Spaceship and it turned out it worked but after I used an amount of nodes which I dont rememeber at the moment, the Extension Crashed. So you would need to know the limits of Today extension and Spritekit together. And it would be really  nice of you if you could upload a sample using UIKit

Comment: It is possible. I am using Widgets in all my SpriteKit games.

Answer (score 0):

I made a framework with the intention to solve this problem some months ago, [link here](https://github.com/Felizolinha/WidGame). I haven't had time to test it properly in iOS 11, so there might be some new bugs.

The only working solution I found to use SpriteKit with Today Extensions was to create the SKView and present the scene in `viewWillTransition(to size:with coordinator:)`. This is necessary because Today Extensions have a different life cycle than a normal application, [look at these iOS Widget Gotchas](https://github.com/iosphere/ISHWeiss/blob/master/content/widgets.md) to get more detailed information on how this works.
EDIT: The correct method to setup these things might now be viewWillAppear in iOS 11, but it might be necessary to do some testing.

Another really important thing to consider when creating widget games is that you have very little memory(16mb if I recall correctly) to build your game with. You have to reduce your memory usage at all costs, otherwise the widget will crash and display a message telling you that it was unable to load.